# Getting undefine variable error while passing data from one blade to anouther in view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone please tell me where i am wrong,

Just want to send one variable from one blade through include but getting error.The code in view is

```
@include('core::partials/breadcrumb/breadcrumb-list', array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb,'value'=>'none'))
```

and when i display this variable using `{{$value}}` giving me error.

Please help me out

Comment: Undefine variable error details good read is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly entered view name.

It should be:-

```
@include('view.name', array('some'=>'data'))
```

Refer [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

Comment: THANKS FOR REPLYING BUT WHERE i AM WRONG DIDN'T FIND

Comment: @user2110253 should be `@include('core::partials.breadcrumb.breadcrumb-list', array(....`

Comment: @user2110253: Can you please share your folder structure? Why do you need to write core? you can access view from nested folder directly like **'folder1.folder2.folder3.filename'**